# How is it possible to terminate a Chrome Application, that ist not launched via "Launch" activity, but from another application like Powershell?

Tags: powershell, process, automation, blueprism, rpa

When I launch an application via navigate stage and launch action, there are no problems to terminate the application. Currently I am working on a process, that launches Chrome via Powershell. When I am trying to terminate/ close the application, one chrome process is closed. But there are 10 chrome processes in task manager. The chrome-window is not closed.

Here's what I've already tried:
- using navigate stage and terminate action
- identify the window by using win32 mode and afterwards the close action in a navigate stage
- invoke JS fragment: window.close() -> returns, that only windows that have been opened with code can also be closed with code

So what else may I try?

Comment: You specifically said "*it does not work*" - but how do you know? You haven't specified the error messages you're seeing (if any).

Comment: Also - why not just use the Blue Prism-native methodology of Attaching to the running instance and only *then* sending it a Terminate?

Comment: Because the window is not closed in this way

Comment: You can use the `Kill Process` in `Utility - Environment` VBO

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the action "Kill Process" within the `Utility - Environment` VBO to target all open instances of the `chrome.exe` process.

Answer (score 0):

You can always invoke `taskkill` from the command line (or PS):

```
taskkill /IM chrome.exe /F
```

Answer (score 0):

This c# should close every instance of Chrome running (using System.Diagnostics). Place it in a code stage:

```
        Process[] processes;
        string procName = "chrome";
        processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(procName);

        foreach (Process proc in processes)
        {
            proc.CloseMainWindow();
        }
```

If you don't know how, you can see another one of my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57065468/declaring-and-calling-methods-in-blue-prism-global-code-stage/57074266#57074266).

Comment: Do I have to download the System.Diagnostics.dll or shall I add "System.Diagnostics.dll" on the "Initialise"-Page in code options?

Comment: Blue prism uses .NET framework, so all you need to do is place a reference to the .dll and the namespace in the code options tab, in the initialise page. In my other post is shown how to do this, just follow the link in the answer. Then System.Diagnostics should be a framework assembly, is not like a COM .dll (like Interops for Office, etc...), so you should not need to reference a directory location for the .dll or download anything.

Answer (score 0):

This powershell on line will kill all of your chrome process

```
get-process chrome | stop-process
```